# Add custom entry into legend in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to add some manual entry in the legend for explanation of the characters 'A' and 'B' on the left side of the plot. I have no other idea where to put the definition of them.

[image]

So, below "Plot E" in the legend should be something like "A = ...". Is there any way to do this? Or is there another option?

Comment: I haven't used pgfplot very often, so I can't really help with this. However, I can tell you it's always a good idea to attach a working example of your code so people who find your question can work with it and experiment potential solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The combination of `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry` allows to add custom entries. The purpose of the first is to add graphic options and the purpose of the second one is to add the description text.

In your case, the small legend image would probably be nothing but the text "A" or "B" and the description text would... well, describe these groups.

One could define a style which doesn't use a filled area a small legend image, but simply a node with text:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotsset{
    legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \node[anchor=center] at (0.3cm,0cm) {#1};
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    domain=0:4,
]
    \addplot {x};   \addlegendentry{$x$}
    \addplot {x^2}; \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
    \addplot {x^3}; \addlegendentry{$x^3$}
    \addlegendimage{legend image with text=A}
    \addlegendentry{$= 42$}
    \addlegendimage{legend image with text=B}
    \addlegendentry{$\approx 43$}
    \addplot {x^(-1)}; \addlegendentry{$x^{-1}$}
    \addplot {x^(-2)}; \addlegendentry{$x^{-2}$}
    \addplot {x^(-3)}; \addlegendentry{$x^{-3}$}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]