# How to place legend text on the left in a pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the legend of a pgfplot, the text is on the right of the image. Is it possible to move the text to the left of the image for a single entry?

For example, the following LaTeX code will produce a legend that reads

```
[░░] Bad   [▒▒]   [██] Good
```

Instead, I would like to move "Bad" to the left of the legend image and get

```
Bad [░░]   [▒▒]   [██] Good
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with pgfplots?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
Q & A & B & C
Q1 & 0 & 1 & 3
Q2 & 2 & 1 & 1
}{\answers}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend columns=-1,
    legend to name=leg1,
    xbar stacked,
    y=0.8cm, y dir=reverse, xmin=0, xmax=4,
    ytick=data, yticklabels from table={\answers}{Q},
]

    \addplot [fill=red] table [x=A, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=B, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addplot [fill=green] table [x=C, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    
    \legend{Bad, { },Good}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{leg1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add an extra legend entry with the word *Bad* as image and an empty description, then the red and yellow plot as normal legend entries without description, and then the green plot with the word *Good* as description.

This creates a bit of space between the first legend entry (the word *Bad*) and the second entry (the red rectangle), so you can adjust that with some negative kerning.

The code for adding a text 'image' in the legend is taken from [Add custom entry into legend in pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204395/add-custom-entry-into-legend-in-pgfplot).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{
    legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \node[anchor=center] at (0.3cm,0cm) {#1};
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
Q & A & B & C
Q1 & 0 & 1 & 3
Q2 & 2 & 1 & 1
}{\answers}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend columns=-1,
    legend to name=leg1,
    xbar stacked,
    y=0.8cm, y dir=reverse, xmin=0, xmax=4,
    ytick=data, yticklabels from table={\answers}{Q},
]
    \addlegendimage{legend image with text=Bad\kern-3pt}
    \addlegendentry{{}}
    \addplot [fill=red] table [x=A, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addlegendentry{{}}
    \addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=B, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addlegendentry{{}}
    \addplot [fill=green] table [x=C, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addlegendentry{Good}
    
    %\legend{Bad, { },Good}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{leg1}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]