# pgfplots: Weird problem when using `\addlegendentry` with line break

Tags: pgfplots

**Bug/Issue Report: [See here](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/429).**

---

- I want to have an additional multi-line custom entry in the legend (`\addlegendentry`).
- Therefore, I follow [Add custom entry into legend in pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204395/).
- I also want the legend to be left-aligned.
- Somehow, I need **both** (seemingly redundant) following lines to make it work:

---

```
legend style = {
    cells = {align = left}, % When commented out then error occurs
    },          
legend cell align = {left},
```

---

- If I remove `cells = {align = left},` the I get an error.
- If I remove `legend cell align = {left},` then the alignment is centered.
- Can you recreate the problem? Is this a bug that I should report?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend style = {
        cells = {align = left}, % When commented out then error occurs
        },          
    legend cell align = {left},     
    ]
    % Plot A
    \addplot{x^2 - x + 4};
    \addlegendentry{$T_\text{R, I}$}
    % ---
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204395/
    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
    \addlegendentry{
        Line 1\\
        Line 2
        }   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*Error Message*

> ```
> Missing } inserted.
> <inserted text> 
>                 }
> l.27  \end{axis}
> ```

[image]

Comment: "`left` is equivalent to `legend style={cells={anchor=west}}`" - from the manual. Does it work for you if you do `legend style = {cells = {align = left, anchor=west}}` and remove `legend cell align=left`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, that works. (1) Do you agree that the behavior is weird? (2) Feel free to add an answer (just the comment) and I will upvote.

Comment: `align` turns the node into a tabular; that is, the text inside the node is treated like a tabular.  You don't see the effect since `Line 1` and `Line 2` are the same width.  `anchor=west` aligns the entire node (tabular) inside the tikzpicture.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, but *intended* behavior. See the comments in the following code for some explanations.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % this key manages how *different* legend entries are aligned to each other
        legend cell align=right,
        % this key manages how *multi-line* text in a *single* legend entry is aligned.
        % You receive an error because it is *required* to set the `align` option
        % when you have multi-line text. ...
        legend style={cells={align=left}}, % When commented out then error occurs
    ]
        \addplot{x^2 - x + 4};
        \addlegendentry{$T_\text{R, I}$}
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{
            Line 1 \\
            Line number two
        }
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{just some long text}
    \end{axis}

    % ... You'll get the same error if you comment the `align` option here,
    % i.e. this is standard (intended) TikZ behavior.
    \node at (1,1) [
        align=center,
    ] {some \\ text};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was not clear to me. The commands sound very similar and I assumed they are synonyms.

Comment: This can happen. But luckily we places like TeX.SX where you can be brought back on track ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the error, might be worth a bug report.

---

The manual says in the description of `legend cell align` that

> the choice `left` is equivalent to `legend style={cells={anchor=west}}`

And if you do

```
legend style = {cells = {align = left, anchor=west}},
```

while removing `legend cell align=left`, it seems to work as desired.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend style = {cells = {align = left, anchor=west}},
    ]
    % Plot A
    \addplot{x^2 - x + 4};
    \addlegendentry{$T_\text{R, I}$}
    % ---
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204395/
    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
    \addlegendentry{
        Line 1\\
        Line 245
        }   
%    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
%    \addlegendentry{a}
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, I accepted the new answer. I will give +1 to some of your other answers as a thank you.