# Package PGFPLOTS legend empty entry shift to left

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I made a plot with 2 y-axis on the same x-axis. One one the left, one on the right. [image]

Thats the Code I used:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.3}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
            axis y line*=left,
            width = \textwidth,
            height =  10 cm,
            xlabel={Something},
            ylabel={Something},         
            grid=none,
            major grid style={gray!95},
            ]%
            %
            \addplot [line width=1pt, solid,color=black, mark=none]
            table[x=x,y=y, col sep=comma] {Data1.csv};
            \label{Plot1}
    
            \addplot [color=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            table[x=x,y=y, col sep=comma] {Data2.csv};
            \label{Plot2}
            
            \addplot [color=black, mark=diamond*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            table[x=x,y=y, col sep=comma] {Data3.csv};
            \label{Plot3}
            
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
            %   /pgf/number format/000 sep={},
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line = none,
            width = \textwidth,
            height =  10 cm,
            ylabel={Something else},            
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 18,
            ytick align = outside,
            ytick pos = right,
            ylabel near ticks,
            grid=none,
            major grid style={gray!95},
            legend style={font=\small},
            legend columns=1,
            legend cell align={left},
            ]%
            \addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentryexpanded{Headline 1:}
            \addplot[line width=1pt,dashed,color=black, mark=none]
            table[x=x,y=y, col sep=comma] {Data4.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Model prediction}
            
            \addplot[color=black, mark=square*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            table[x=x,y=y, col sep=comma] {Data5.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Experiment 1}
            
            \addplot[color=black, mark=triangle*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            table[x=x,y=ý, col sep=comma] {Data6.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Experiment 2}
            
            \addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentryexpanded{Headline 2:}
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Plot1}\addlegendentryexpanded{Model prediction}
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Plot2}\addlegendentryexpanded{Experiment 1}
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Plot3}\addlegendentryexpanded{Experiment 2}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

What bothers me is the alignment of the headlines in the legend. I am aware, that the "empty entry" takes the space I what the text to be. But is there a way to shift the headline entry in the legend to the left?

FYI: Not using the `\addlegendimage{empty entry}` before the `\addlegendentryexpanded` causes the order to mix up, and the Headline gets assigned a marker from the actual data.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question! Unfortunately we can't compile your code as we don't have your custom `.csv` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204519/36296 to add your headline instead of the legend image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.3}

\pgfplotsset{
    legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \node[anchor=center] at (0.0cm,0cm) {#1};
        }
    },
}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
            axis y line*=left,
            width = \textwidth,
            height =  10 cm,
            xlabel={Something},
            ylabel={Something},         
            grid=none,
            major grid style={gray!95},
            ]%
            %
            \addplot [line width=1pt, solid,color=black, mark=none]
            {x};
            \label{Plot1}
    
            \addplot [color=black, mark=*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            {x};
            \label{Plot2}
            
            \addplot [color=black, mark=diamond*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            {x};
            \label{Plot3}
            
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
            %   /pgf/number format/000 sep={},
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line = none,
            width = \textwidth,
            height =  10 cm,
            ylabel={Something else},            
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 18,
            ytick align = outside,
            ytick pos = right,
            ylabel near ticks,
            grid=none,
            major grid style={gray!95},
            legend style={font=\small},
            legend columns=1,
            legend cell align={left},
            ]%
            \addlegendimage{legend image with text=\makebox[0pt][l]{Headline 1:}}
            \addlegendentry{}
            \addplot[line width=1pt,dashed,color=black, mark=none]
            {x};
            \addlegendentry{Model prediction}
            
            \addplot[color=black, mark=square*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            {x};
            \addlegendentry{Experiment 1}
            
            \addplot[color=black, mark=triangle*, only marks,mark size=2pt]
            {x};
            \addlegendentry{Experiment 2}
            
            \addlegendimage{legend image with text=\makebox[0pt][l]{Headline 2:}}
            \addlegendentry{}
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Plot1}\addlegendentryexpanded{Model prediction}
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Plot2}\addlegendentryexpanded{Experiment 1}
            \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Plot3}\addlegendentryexpanded{Experiment 2}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]